# How can I obtain unique answer by hyperparameter tuning?

Tags: matlab, svm

I want to train a SVM classifier in matlab and find the best hyperparameters for it by K-fold cross-validation then find classification accuracy for another data set by using that model. so I wrote following code:

```
Mdl = fitcsvm(trainingData,labels,'OptimizeHyperparameters','auto',...
'HyperparameterOptimizationOptions',struct('Optimizer','gridsearch','AcquisitionFunctionName',...
    'expected-improvement-per-second','MaxObjectiveEvaluation',10,'ShowPlots',false,'Verbose',0));
label = predict(Mdl,testData);
```

my problem is every time I run this code and then calculate the classification accuracy I get different result. what is the problem? and how can I fix it?
I will appreciate any idea.

Answer (score 0):

Acquisition functions whose names include per-second do not yield reproducible results because the optimization depends on the runtime of the objective function.
Look in the page https://it.mathworks.com/help/stats/bayesian-optimization-workflow.html